# Package breakurl Error: The breakurl depends on hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, urls, incompatibility

After upgrading `TexLive` from `2014` to `2016`, I started getting the following error when use `breakurl` package. Any idea to fix this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks

> ! Package breakurl Error: The breakurl depends on hyperref
>   package.

Comment: I get the same error with TeX Live from 2012 on with a document that just loads `breakurl` in its preamble. So you have changed something else, or a package that used to load `hyperref` doesn't any longer. An example of a document working in TL 2014 and not in TL 2016 is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the breakurl package *after* hyperref.